# Serialize array of enum in identityDbContext

Tags: c#, serialization, enums, asp.net-identity, dbcontext

I'm trying to serialize an array of enums to store in the database as a string. I achieved it with a normal DbContext but when I try to do it in a IdentityDbContext I get different errors. This is how I serialized it in a normal DBcontext

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
             modelBuilder.Entity<Spel>().Property(p => p.Bord)
             .HasConversion(
                v => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v),
                v => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Kleur[,]>(v));
}
```

And this is how it looks in my IndentityDBcontext (I have to mention that I changed the ModelBuilder to DBModelbuilder cause otherwise it got an error saying that the override methode was not suitable.)

```
public class SpelerContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
    {
        public SpelerContext(DbContextOptions<SpelerContext> options) : base(options) { }

        public DbSet<Speler> Spelers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Spel> Spels { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Spel>().Property(p => p.Bord)
            .HasConversion(
                v => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v),
                v => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Kleur[,]>(v));
        }

    }
```

The error says
**" Cannot implicitly convert type Kleur[*,*] to 'string' "**
And if I try with a property that is a enum and not a list of enums I get the error **"'PrimitivePropertyConfiguration' does not contain a definition for 'HasConversion' and no accessible extension method 'HasConversion' accepting a first argument of type 'PrimitivePropertyConfiguration' could be found"**.

I also get an error in the constructor in the options parameter. I get **The type 'ReversiRestApi.DAL.SpelerContext' cannot be used as type parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method 'DbContextOptions'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'ReversiRestApi.DAL.SpelerContext' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext'**.

I see everywhere everyone says that to migrate from DBContext to identityDbcontext you only have to change the parentclass but I don't know why everything goes so wrong when I do that.

I have been trying to solve this but I can't find a solution and there is no online support for this specific issue. I would greatly appreciate who can help me.

Comment: The first sample code runs in EF Core. The second example you are trying to run in EF 6.

Comment: That was the problem!Thank you very much